# Image View in custom Table View Cell resizes unexpectedly after touch or scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have a custom table cell inside a table view, which contains a horizontal stack view of image view and text field... The image view mode is ScaleAspectFit

When the view loads initially, the views are arranged as they should be, but when a cell is touched or the table view is scrolled, the image view resizes unexpectedly

Here are screenshots and my code

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ImagesTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImagesTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    let pic = self.patient!.images[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageViewPic.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.imageViewPic.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    cell.imageViewPic.image = getImage(pic.imagePath)
    cell.labelPic.text = pic.caption
    cell.imageViewPic.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.labelPic.tag = indexPath.row

    return cell
}
```

I tried all Content Modes with no benefit

[image: initial loading]

[image: image in second after touch resizes unexpectedly]

Edit2: here is getImage() function code as requested

```
func getImage(filename: String) -> UIImage {
    let path =         getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent(filename)
    let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)
    return image!
}
```

Comment: if you using auto layout which constraints imageview have already? Also in such situations Reveal or Xcode View Debugging feature will handy.

Comment: Could you post your getImage function code?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `clipsToBounds` property of `UIImageView` to `true`.

Like

set `cell.imageViewPic.clipsToBounds=true`

Also check the constraint of the imageview. It should be `center vertical align`,`leading`, `fixed width` and `fixed height`.

Comment: @Hadi what about constraint?

Answer (score 0):

try below steps it may can help you.

> 1. render ImageView with fixe width and height
> 2. make `clipSubviews  = YES`. in story board  OR `cell.imageViewPic.clipsToBounds = YES;`